# Automating REST API without using cURL

Tags: rest, unix

Is there any other way to automate REST API call without using cURL command in Unix? See I have to update/insert/delete records into a MySQL table everyday. The problem is in our server when I use cURL command, it shutdowns or makes the server unavailable/inaccessible via browser. I have search for the reason why this is happening but still got no answer. I think, it's something to do with server's security.

Anyways, I'm now force to find another way to make this happen and most of my searches always suggest to use cURL.

Do you have any alternative?

Comment: You need to figure out why the server is shutting down. Avoiding cURL isn't the right way to tackle the problem.

Comment: This is only a half-joke: have you tried `wget`? Otherwise I agree with @JohnKugelman

Comment: Yeah. I really need to talk about this matter with our database admins. Thanks for the help anyway.